# Div need vertical center of the screen after page scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` which needs to be vertically centered in the screen after page scrolling

Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/JtZ7F/

```
<div style="height:1000px; border:1px solid red;">
    scroll
    <span style="height:150px; width:100px; float:right; border:1px solid green; display:block; position:fixed;top:50%; margin-top:-75px;">
        need vertical center of the screen after page scroling
    </span>
</div>
```

Now I am using `position:fixed;`, it's not a solution

I want when I stop the page scrolling  my green box smoothly moves to vertical center of the screen.

How can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: Can you show the jQuery work you have done so far?

Comment: Why is `position: fixed` not a solution for you?

Comment: @Liam Spencer - actually i am not a jQuery expert. Do u have any simple script?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - because now when we page scrolling green box still fixed , no it's not a solution, i want when we stop the page scrolling then green box move to vertical center of the page, clear?

Answer (score 4):

Add this function in your jquery :

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {   
this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");    
 this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");     return this; }
```

Add a id to your span "test" and write the below in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('#test').center(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks your help, but I am sorry to say, now when we page scrolling green box still fixed , no it's not a solution, i want when we stop the page scrolling then green box move to vertical center of the page, clear?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it, tested in Chrome & IE7+, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VF7E/) for an example.

```
$.fn.center = function () {
                    return this.css({
                        'left': ($(window).width() / 2) - $(this).width() / 2,
                        'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - $(this).height() / 2,
                        'position': 'fixed'
                    });
                };
```

Usage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(element).center();
});
```